# The equation $5^x+2=17^y$ doesn't have solutions in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

**Problem:** Prove that the equation $5^x+2=17^y$ doesn't have any solutions with $x,y$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

I've been analyzing the remainder while dividing by $4$, but I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: The left-hand side ends is equal to $7\mod 10$ and that might put some kind of restriction on the right-hand side. I think you can show that $y\overset{!}{=}4n+1$ to have $17^y\equiv 7\mod 10$.

Comment: LHS can be written as $(4+1)^x+2$ which gives remainder 3 when divided by 4 while RHS is $(16+1)^y$ which gives remainder 1 , hence no solution!

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal How can you get the reminder of $(4+1)^x+2$ when dividing by 4?

Comment: @user143201 okay I'll write down the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we consider the LHS i.e $$5^x+2$$ it can be written as $$(4+1)^x+2=1+4k+2$$ where $k$ is some positive integer which we get using binomial expansion thus we see that LHS gives remainder $3$ always when divided by $4$. While if you see the RHS i.e $$17^y=(16+1)^y=1+16m$$ where we get $m$ again by using binomial exapnsion , so RHS leaves remainder $1$ always on division by $4$ .Thus there's no solution

Comment: Very nice trick!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: as you say, take the equation modulo $4$, that is, $$5^x + 2 \equiv 17^y \mod 4.$$ The rules of modular arithmetic allow you to substitute reduced representatives modulo $4$ for the bases of the exponents, namely for $5$ and for $17$. What do you get after making the substitutions?

Comment: I'm pretty new to the modular Arithmetic rules. Can you remind me what rule can I use.

Comment: This is repeated application of the following rule: if $a \equiv c \mod n$ and $b \equiv d \mod n$, then $ab\equiv cd \mod n$. As a consequence, you can prove by induction that if $k \equiv \ell \mod n$, then $k^x \equiv \ell^x \mod n$, for $x \in \mathbb N$; you may have this as another separate rule.